# Variable/Index within head of a loop

Tags: twig

I have a for-loop within another for-loop and I would like the inner for-loop to go through the array `test[INDEX]` with `[INDEX]` being the index of the outer for-loop. I know I can get the loops index with the variable `{{ loop.index() }}`, however I do not know how to apply that within the head of my inner loop.

I've tried `{% for x in test.{{ loop.index0 }} %}`, but that throws me the error

> Expected name or number.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In twig you can also use the array notation to get values from a variable

A note here is that the default `loop.index` is `1 indexed` so you might want to use `loop.index0` to get the correct offset

```html
{% for f in foo %}
    - {{ f }}: {{ bar[loop.index0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

As an alternative you can also get the key in the `{% for key, value ...`  format

```html
{% for key, value in foo %}
    - {{ value }}: {{ bar[key] }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/sqx9tl)

---

**edit**

As for you comment, you can succesfuly use this in any inner-loop, here is a more readable example

```html
{% for country in countries %}
    {{ country }}:
    {% if cities[loop.index0]|default %}
    <ul>
        {% for city in cities[loop.index0] %}
        <li>{{ city }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/sqx9tl/2)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand how to apply this in the head of my loop.
When I try `{% for termin in test[loop.index0] %}` it now throws me the error
> Notice: Undefined index: loop

Comment: Why would you try to have that in the outer-loop?

Comment: I don't. As per my original question, I want the INNER-LOOP to go through `test[INDEX OF OUTER-LOOP]`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Like I mentioned in my last comment, `{% for termin in test[loop.index0] %}` throws me the error `Notice: Undefined index: loop`

Comment: Then please update your question with your current twig template, a dump of the data and expected output